# REST WEBAPI POST method with parameters not being called

Tags: http, rest, http-post, asp.net-web-api

I have built a REST API with a controller having a POST method with 4 parameters like this-

```
 [HttpPost]
    public void SaveSession([FromBody] string userId, [FromBody] DateTime issueDateTime, [FromBody] string browserType, [FromBody] string salt)
    {
        // Params need to be changed
        _sessionService.SaveSession(userId, issueDateTime, browserType, salt);
    }
```

How should I POST data on the client side, I mean what should be the format of the data to be sent?

I tried this format-

```
"userId=abc&DateTime=someDatetime&browserType=somebrowser&salt=somesalt"
```

Its not working if I try this, The web service method is not even being called

Could anyone tell me the correct format?

EDIT:
Here is how I am calling the API-

```
            const string endPoint = @"http://localhost:85/session/Test";
            var postData = "userId=abc&DateTime=someDatetime&browserType=somebrowser&salt=somesalt"
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(EndPoint + parameters);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postData) && Method == HttpVerb.POST)
            {
                var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(postData);
                request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

                using (var writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
            {
                var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                    throw new ApplicationException(message);
                }

                // grab the response
                var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    xmlDoc.Load(responseStream);
                }
                return (xmlDoc);
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: show us your call to the API, your problem is likely in that portion of the process

Comment: Thanks Kristian, I have edited the post. Could you please check and let me know whats wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know, what mistake I was doing. I was sending 4 parameters in a WebService method. We  can only send one parameter while calling a web service method. If you want to send multiple data, just send it as an object. Like this -

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveSession([FromBody] Values value)
{
    var userId = values.userId,
    var issueDateTime= values.issueDateTime,
    var browserType= values.browserType,
    var salt= values.salt,

    _sessionService.SaveSession(userId, issueDateTime, browserType, salt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume routing has been properly configured.

Said so.... DateTime parameter in the controller method has been named "issueDateTime" while within the request has been named "DateTime".